# how to get array inside for each loop in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

In my blade component I am entering this:

```
 {{  $post['tags']->pluck('slug') }}
```

but getting the following result:

```
["abc","pqr"]
```

`$post['tags']->slug` is giving an error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use foreach :

```
@foreach($post['tags']->pluck('slug') as $key => $slug)
    {{ $slug }}
@endforeach
```